# support for add_to_set defined in Mongoid::Atomic::Modifiers?

Tags: ruby, mongoid

Hi I'm new to mongodb,

Need support for `add_to_set` method which add a document in a collection

What if `add_to_set` is called twice and in both time the inserted value are equal

for example

```
    someInstance.add_to_set(some_field: "hello_world")
```

if this called twice will it be an update query for mongo??

Answer (score 0):

It'll call mongo, cause the action is atomic, so local state is not 100% db state, but it won't sdd same item twice. So the answer is yes.